# O que significa o argumento alpha da função ltsReg, do pacote robustbase?

Tags: r, regressão

Tenho uma pergunta sobre o uso do argumento `alpha` da função `ltsReg` do pacote `robustbase`.

Pelo que entendi, ele é responsável por determinar o tamanho dos subconjuntos que serão utilizados para fazer o ajuste do modelo para estes subconjuntos, selecionando o modelo do subconjunto que apresentou os menores resíduos ao quadrado.

Geralmente, o valor adotado para `lts` é de 0,5, mas o argumento `alpha` permite que você forneça um valor entre 0,5 e 1. Desta forma, se eu usar o valor 1, o meu ajuste deve ser equivalente ao ajuste OLS? Ou eu estou interpretado errado o argumento alfa?

Comment: Olá Machado, eu não consegui achar essa função `ItsReg` que você está falando. Que biblioteca ela pertence?

Comment: Perdão, era lstReg do pacote rubustbase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As estimativas deverão ser equivalentes quando você usar `alpha = 1`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
> library(robustbase)
> data(heart)
> coef(ltsReg(clength ~ height + weight, data = heart, alpha = 1))
 Intercept     height     weight 
20.3757645  0.2107473  0.1910949 
> coef(lm(clength ~ height + weight, data = heart))
(Intercept)      height      weight 
 20.3757645   0.2107473   0.1910949
```

O que pode acontecer é que para a `ltsReg` não existe uma forma fechada p/ obter as estimativas então elas são obtidas de forma computacional ao contrário da regressão linear simples. Por isso, podem acontecer diferenças de aproximação.

Veja as funções que são minimizadas na regressão linear simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e na linear trimmed squares:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se `k = n` o que acontece com `alpha = 1`, as funções ficam iguais. Portanto as estimativas também serão iguais.

Comment: Então, interpretei de forma correta o argumento porém infelizmente para os meus dados o ajuste não fica igual.                                                   `> coef(ltsReg(log(ALT) ~ I(1/DAP) + log(MhDomPar), data = RelaHipso,alpha=1))
    Intercept      I(1/DAP) log(MhDomPar) 
    2.4233549   -10.2901524     0.3176276 
> coef(lm(log(ALT) ~ I(1/DAP) + log(MhDomPar), data = RelaHipso))
  (Intercept)      I(1/DAP) log(MhDomPar) 
    2.2044777    -9.1188267     0.3707975`